# Como asigno un archivo de excel que yo elija con VBE

Tags: excel, vba, vb

Encontre este codigo y me interesa utilizarlo para mi proyecto excel, el problema es que me crea automaticamente un nuevo archivo excel, lo que me gustaria hacer es que se seleccione un archivo especifico que yo elija creo que la parte del codigo en donde puedo hacerlo es esta

> Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
> oXL.Visible = True

https://support.microsoft.com/es-ve/help/219905/how-to-dynamically-add-and-run-a-vba-macro-from-visual-basic

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
      Dim oXL As Excel.Application
      Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
      Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
      Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
      Dim sMsg As String
      
    ' Create a new instance of Excel and make it visible.
      Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      oXL.Visible = True
   
    ' Add a new workbook and set a reference to Sheet1.
      Set oBook = oXL.Workbooks.Add
      Set oSheet = oBook.Sheets(1)
      
    ' Demo standard Automation from out-of-process,
    ' this routine simply fills in values of cells.
      sMsg = "Fill the sheet from out-of-process"
      MsgBox sMsg, vbInformation Or vbMsgBoxSetForeground
      
      For i = 1 To 100
         For j = 1 To 10
            sMsg = "Cell(" & Str(i) & "," & Str(j) & ")"
            oSheet.Cells(i, j).Value = sMsg
         Next j
      Next i
      
    ' You're done with the first test, now switch sheets
    ' and run the same routine via an inserted Microsoft Visual Basic 
    ' for Applications macro.
      MsgBox "Done.", vbMsgBoxSetForeground
      Set oSheet = oBook.Sheets.Add
      oSheet.Activate
      
      sMsg = "Fill the sheet from in-process"
      MsgBox sMsg, vbInformation Or vbMsgBoxSetForeground
      
    ' The Import method lets you add modules to VBA at
    ' run time. Change the file path to match the location
    ' of the text file you created in step 3.
      oXL.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import "C:\KbTest.bas"
   
    ' Now run the macro, passing oSheet as the first parameter
      oXL.Run "DoKbTest", oSheet
      
    ' You're done with the second test
      MsgBox "Done.", vbMsgBoxSetForeground
      
    ' Turn instance of Excel over to end user and release
    ' any outstanding object references.
      oXL.UserControl = True
      Set oSheet = Nothing
      Set oBook = Nothing
      Set oXL = Nothing
      
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Set oBook = oXL.Workbooks.Add`

Esa línea de comando lo que hace es **crear** un nuevo archivo Excel vacío. Si lo quieres asignar a uno existente, tienes varias opciones:

1. Si el archivo no está abierto (es el método más fácil), entonces utiliza `Open`:

`Set oBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open("ruta a tu archivo.xlsx")`

2. Si el archivo ya lo tienes abierto, estará en la colección `Workbooks`, puedes asignarlo usando su nombre entre comillas, o su número si lo conoces, entonces algo de este tipo debería funcionarte:

`Set oBook = Workbooks("NombreArchivo")` o `Set oBook = oXL.Workbooks(1)`

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me ayudo a resolver lo que necesitaba amigo. Se aprecia !